# Moving boot disc to another

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd, btrfs

I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed on a Corsair SSD but am becoming a little nervous at the increase of smart errors appearing from it.

I am considering the purchase of a new SSD to take over the role but don't want to reinstall Ubuntu, my programs, configs, etc. from fresh.

If I use clonezilla to image the disc to my BTRFS array and then use that to write to the new SSD, edit grub and reboot, will that work for me?

Am I missing a step or two?

My system has,

- 120GB Corsair SSD mounted at /
- 4 x 3TB hard drives in a BTRFS RAID 1 array mounted at /mnt/btrfs
- 1 x 1TB hard drive containing Windows 8.1 with an option to use it in Grub.
- Ubuntu 14.10
- 32GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Clonezilla on and off for perhaps four years and rather heavily for the past year.  Its menus can seem obtuse at first but I find it easy to use.

If you were to create an image of your Corsaire on your raid, you certainly ought to be able to restore that image to the next SSD you purchase, but there's another way to go.  You could use clonezilla to clone the Corsaire DIRECTLY to the new drive and save a step.